# Can you help me finding relevant literature about continuous application of Boolean operators?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, continuity, boolean-algebra

All numbers that can be noted in the decimal system can also be noted in the binary system.

The binary system has boolean operators. Some basic boolean operators are: and $\land$, or $\lor$ and not $\lnot$. I don't know any corresponding operators in the decimal system.

As far as I've learnt about boolean operations, they are discrete. But, you can represent real numbers in the binary system:

$\pi = 3.1415926535..._{10} = 11.0010010000111111..._2$

and so you can apply boolean operators on real numbers. Which makes them continous.

So I would like to learn what happens, if boolean operators are used in a continous way but not discrete. I am specially interested in the xor operator, which has fascinating properties and is defined as:

$A \oplus B = (A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$

Finally, I would like to examine things like: $\pi \oplus \sqrt{2}$

```
Question: Can you give me references to literature about continuous applications of boolean logic, or 
can you show me meaningful keywords of the more general matter?
```

For instance, Boolean algebra is a special case of a De Morgan algebra. Or it could be in the context of modular arighmetic. But I don't know if it makes sense to search there. I didn't found suitable papers by searching with "continuous applications of boolean operators" or else. There is also "continuous logic" but this is something different.

Comment: I am new on this side and did my best to read the guide and to write a question fitting to rules :-) feel free to show me more how to improve. Thank you.

Comment: At first I thought to be possibly relevant are continuous logics that are dealt with (among other places, I'm sure) in a book I have, [**Continuous Model Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691079293) by Chang/Keisler (Chapter II is "*Continuous Logics*"), although this is likely way too advanced to be of any use to you. But then I noticed you exclude "continuous logic", considering it not to be what you're interested in. **(continued)**

Comment: Perhaps continuously applied is not the appropriate phrase, but rather infinitely applied Boolean operations. Maybe infinitary logic --- See [[1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/)] and [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic)].

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro  Yeah, it seems not so easy to find suitable names or keywords for this. Thank you for your keywords, I see there is a lot to search. // I realize right now, the result function of "continuous xor usage" (however) might not be continuous any longer, as "bits" are switched on and off, which creates steps. So, the "Nowhere continuous function" loosely pops into mind.